# can i save data without static method using asp.net and ajax?

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax

When I want to save data without static method on my ASP.Net using Ajax I could not hit the server side. But when I make it static it works good. But I need save data without static.
my code is below. I want save data without static using ajax.

```
public static int SaveCountry(string countryName, string countryAbout)
{
    try
    {
        country = new Country(countryName, countryAbout);
        int result = countryEntryManager.SetCountryInformation(country);
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    GetCountryInformation();
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some more code? I guess you're not directly calling this method from your client side, right? Could you show where this method is called, the action method or so?

Comment: It's not clear what keeps you from removing the `static` keyword, but is clear that your method cannot work as it is now unless `countryEntryManager.SetCountryInformation` is static as well.

Comment: ... and your `GetCountryInformation()` will never get hit - static or not.

Comment: are you using webmethod, service or web api?

Answer (score 0):

Without Static Mathod serverside ajax call is not possible

Comment: I want any tipe of Action without static . It can be save or any tipe of action. for example :

Comment: I want any tipe of Action without static . It can be save or any tipe of action. for example : public int Message(int msg){
   return msg;
}

suppose if i send 100 by this 'msg' parameter. then it will give me alert message and return 100.
i want it will work by ajax without static. static means 'public static int Message(int msg).....'